# TypeError: AutoMLConfig() takes no arguments in Azure Synapse

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse, automl

I am receiving below error in Azure synapse Pyspark notebook

TypeError: AutoMLConfig() takes no arguments

while running below code:

automl_settings = {
"primary_metric": 'r2_score',
"enable_early_stopping": True,
"experiment_timeout_hours": 0.5,
"max_cores_per_iteration": 1,
"max_concurrent_iterations": 2,
"enforce_time_on_windows": True,
"exclude_nan_labels": True,
"enable_tf": False,
"verbosity": 20
}

automl_config = AutoMLConfig("task": 'regression',
"label_column_name": label,
"compute_target": compute_target,
"featurization": 'auto',
"training_data": train_data
**automl_settings)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong version of Apache spark pool. If you change to a pool with version 2.4, then it should fix your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).